# Is it possible to add base map imagery using QGIS2Web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

Is it possible to add satellite base map imagery using QGIS2Web?
I can't seem to add it using the Export to web map functionality.

[image]

Also, when I select two base maps and export my map using QGIS2Web neither of them show?

Comment: Do you mean add another satellite "basemap" which is not in the list? Re: your second point, can you say whether you are using Leaflet or OpenLayers format?